# Why are some Bluetooth devices susceptible to ping floods and some are not?

Tags: bluetooth, flooding, ping

Just for fun, I've ping flooded my bluetooth speaker at home using l2ping on Linux and I was unable to connect to it as the pinging continued. I've tried flooding my phone and it seems to have received the packets as I got a response (just like the responses i got from my speaker), but I was still able to connect it to my laptop and send files in between. So my question is, why are some devices susceptible to such attack and some not? Is there a mechanism used by my phone that my speaker doesn't use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of Denial Of Service attack. You need to exhaust the resources of the victim in order to make a successful attack. The memory on a smartphone is way more than that of a Bluetooth speaker and so that attack has to be of a much larger scale even without any additional countermeasures deployed in the smartphone.

Comment: What kind of countermeasures could the phone deploy in this case?

Comment: @Doesitmatter for one it can rate limit the type and amount of connections that come in